# How can I help SpecConstr in GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc, repa, data-parallel-haskell

I'm using GHC 7.4.1 to try to compile a program that uses Repa. But partway through compilation, I'm running out of memory. With `ghc -v`, I can see that it's getting stuck in the SpecConstr phase.

SpecConstr is one of GHC's Core-to-Core transformations. Simon Peyton Jones has a nice description [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/spec-constr/spec-constr.pdf), and there's some code [here](http://darcs.haskell.org/ghc/compiler/specialise/SpecConstr.lhs), but it's pretty slow-going for me since I'm not very familiar with the inner workings of GHC.

I'd like to be able to help the compiler along somehow - is there a way to tell where it's getting stuck? Alternatively, is there a way to limit memory usage in this phase until I can recompile on a bigger machine?

Thanks,
Chad

Comment: On a whim, I removed a `computeUnboxedS`, and now it compiles just fine. Still no idea why, though.

Comment: if you post your code, we might be able to tell you why.  Sight unseen, I'm going to guess you bogoned the teutonic matrix, and the jeffries tubes were hyper-ventilated.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can't post the whole thing, and it's not clear how to distill to a minimal case. I had hoped there might be a general procedure for tracking what part of SpecConstr is causing the blowup. Maybe heap profiling GHC itself, or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try compiling with the flags `-fspec-constr-threshold=n` and `-fspec-constr-count=n`.  More details are in the [GHC docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/flag-reference.html).  With 7.4.1, the defaults are n=200 for the threshold and n=3 for the count.

Without seeing code, though, it's possible you're running into [this bug](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2598).  In which case you may need to entirely disable the specconstr pass if the above options aren't sufficient.

Comment: Nice, thank yoU! I don't see any references to the flags you mention, but somehow I had tried `-fno-specialise` but overlooked `-fspec-constr` entirely.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to John L's answer, ensure you compile with the flag `-fno-liberate-case`. The liberate case transform tends to cause code-blowup, which then makes SpecConstr's job harder.